# How can I find out if my domain has been added to email blacklists?

Tags: email, spam

We do a lot of mass emailing of our contacts to promote events, send out newsletters, etc.  Some people read and react, some people unsubscribe, but I fear that some might actually mark the email as spam.

Is there any way to figure out whether my domain has been added to email blacklists or spam registries?

Also, if I use a service like MailChimp to send the emails, how would this work?  If one unscrupulous customer was using MailChimp for evil, wouldn't it affect all of their customers?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From, "[How do I know if I’m on a SPAM Blacklist?](http://www.pinpointe.com/blog/how-do-i-know-if-im-on-a-spam-blacklist)"

- [MXToolbox](http://www.mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx) is free. Enter the email service IP addresses and mxtoolbox checks about 100 blacklists.
- [DNSStuff](http://www.dnsstuff.com) is an inexpensive (almost free) service where you can check 97 blacklists. Includes other DNS and network tools too.
- [(Domain Name System Blacklist)](http://www.dnsbl.info). Free service. Checks about 80 blacklists.

**Update**

Mailchimp, and other services like it, take advantage of every tool and resource to keep their mail from being flagged as spam and that includes following all anti-spam laws. One user, or even a bunch of users, won't get them into trouble because they actively police their and deal with spammers directly and often times catch them before they are successful in sending mass quantities of spam. This keeps their reputation with blacklists in good order and prevents them from being blacklisted.

Keep in mind that this doesn't mean your mail won't be flagged as spam. Mail server blacklists are just one way to catch spam. Bad subject lines and use of "spammy" keywords can still result in emails being flagged as spam.

Comment: Thanks John.  I actually just checked that out myself.  See my edit - the situation is a tad more complicated.

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Mailchimp email always get flagged as promotional and I never read them, even if I would like to ...